# Parsing a JSON using specific key words using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to parse a JSON of a sites stock.

The JSON: https://www.ssense.com/en-us/men/sneakers.json

So I want to take some keywords from the user. Then I want to parse the JSON using these keywords to find the name of the item and (in this specific case) return the ID, SKU and the URL.

So for example:
If I inputted "Black Fennec" I want to parse the JSON and find the ID,SKU, and URL of Black Fennec Sneakers (that have an ID of 3297299, a SKU of 191422M237006, and a url of /men/product/ps-paul-smith/black-fennec-sneakers/3297299 )

I have never attempted doing anything like this. Based on some guides that show how to parse a JSON I started out with this:

```
r = requests.Session()
stock = r.get("https://www.ssense.com/en-us/men/sneakers.json",headers = headers)
obj json_data = json.loads(stock.text)
```

However I am now confused. How do I find the product based off the keywords and how do I get the ID,Url and the SKU or it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theres a number of ways to handle the output. not sure what you want to do with it. But this should get you going.

EDIT 1:

```
import requests

r = requests.Session()
obj_json_data = r.get("https://www.ssense.com/en-us/men/sneakers.json").json()

products = obj_json_data['products']


keyword = input('Enter a keyword: ')

for product in products:
    if keyword.upper() in product['name'].upper():
        name = product['name']
        id_var = product['id']
        sku = product['sku']
        url = product['url']
        print ('Product: %s\nID: %s\nSKU: %s\nURL: %s' %(name, id_var, sku, url))
        # if you only want to return the first match, uncomment next line
        #break
```

I also have it setup to store it into a dataframe, and or a list too. Just to give some options of where to go with it.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.Session()
obj_json_data = r.get("https://www.ssense.com/en-us/men/sneakers.json").json()

products = obj_json_data['products']



keyword = input('Enter a keyword: ')

products_found = []
results = pd.DataFrame()
for product in products:
    if keyword.upper() in product['name'].upper():
        name = product['name']
        id_var = product['id']
        sku = product['sku']
        url = product['url']
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[name, id_var, sku, url]], columns=['name','id','sku','url'])
        results = results.append(temp_df)
        products_found = products_found.append(name)
        print ('Product: %s\nID: %s\nSKU: %s\nURL: %s' %(name, id_var, sku, url))

if products_found == []:
    print ('Nothing found')
```

EDIT 2: Here is another way to do it by converting the json to a dataframe, then filtering by those rows that have the keyword in the name (this is actually a better solution in my opinion)

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

r = requests.Session()
obj_json_data = r.get("https://www.ssense.com/en-us/men/sneakers.json").json()

products = obj_json_data['products']
products_df = json_normalize(products)

keyword = input('Enter a keyword: ')

products_found = []
results = pd.DataFrame()

results = products_df[products_df['name'].str.contains(keyword, case = False)]
#print (results[['name', 'id', 'sku', 'url']])

products_found = list(results['name'])
if products_found == []:
    print ('Nothing found')
else:
    print ('Found: '+ str(products_found))
```

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you so much. I will definitely look into this and get back to you

Comment: the key is just trying to figure out how to "unpack" that obj_json_data that you stored. It can be tricky, but that more you play around, the easier it gets. Just stick with it. You had a good starting point, so seems like you were picking up some good stuff from the guides you were following. If you like the answer, be sure to accept it.

Comment: Accepted the answer but wanted to ask: Is it possible to make it where it doesn't iterate over each product with the keyword and just choose the first one?

Comment: yes. added a way to do this without iterrating. see edit 2. and then so your follow up, you just want it to return the first match it gets? if that's the case, just add `break`. see edit 1 in the first code above

Comment: Ahh ok got it. Thank you for your time